# How to use Yahoo YUI in SuiteCRM

Tags: yui, suitecrm

I am learning SuiteCRM and have a longway to go.  I have never used Yahoo's YUI library.
I am wanting to create a popup dialog in the AOS_Quotes Edit View page with some ajax calls and noticed in some examples that SuiteCRM makes use of Yahoo's YUI. I searched the documentation and after several search engine searches, I was not able to find anything that tells me how I include the YUI library.

Can someone direct me to how I make use of YUI in SuiteCRM and some direction on how popup's and ajax calls are made?

Thank you.

Still Learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SuiteCRM deprecated and totally removed YUI library with version 7.11.16

You can use existing SuiteCRM backend methods to save data using ajax and create your own popups with jQuery (latest version have an updated jQuery version)

For example, saving a field could be done with QuickEdit calls Sending these params in the call:

```
module: Home
action: saveHTMLField
field: phone_office
current_module: Accounts
id: 123-123-123-123
value: 563-1231-3355
view: DetailView
parent_type: 
to_pdf: true
```

Again, don't use YUI, and if you don't need to tweak an existing popup create your own popup and use existing AJAX calls, just pay attention to the developer console (network tab) while using the CRM.

Comment: Thank yo uvery much.  The current version I am working with is 7.11.15 which might explain why I am seeing it in some code but not finding any documentation on it.  I certainly know how to use Jquery and will research more ont he QuickEdit calls.